# Hash a string to several (100-200) unsigned ints

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the logic defined on [this website](http://www.lastfm.de/user/RJ/journal/2007/04/10/rz_libketama_-_a_consistent_hashing_algo_for_memcache_clients). One of the steps is:

> - Hash each server string to several (100-200) unsigned ints

But I am confused with this. Could anybody please tell me what this means so that I can implement the logic manually?

```
// This count is always 2 as per my current setup
int availableservers = Client.getAvailableServers().size();  

String key = "MyKey";
int keyid = key.hashCode();
int v = keyid % 1;
String valess = (String) mcc.get(key,v);
```

Comment: This doesn't like a Java question. As far as I could interpret, the point you highlight means creating a hash e.g. something like MD5 checksum. Take a look at [Hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Answer (score 3):

The article you've referenced contains a link to their SVN code base:

`svn://svn.audioscrobbler.net/misc/ketama/`

In here, they appear to have included a Java implementation:

`svn://svn.audioscrobbler.net/misc/ketama/java_ketama/SockIOPool.java`

In the code you'll find the following:

```
for(long j = 0; j < factor; j++) {
  byte[] d = md5.digest((servers[i]+"-"+j).getBytes());
  for(int h=0;h<4;h++) {
    Long k = 
        ((long)(d[3+h*4]&0xFF) << 24)
      | ((long)(d[2+h*4]&0xFF) << 16)
      | ((long)(d[1+h*4]&0xFF) << 8)
      | ((long)(d[0+h*4]&0xFF));
    buckets.put(k, servers[i]);
    log.debug( "++++ added " + servers[i] + " to server bucket" );
  }             
}
```

This code is creating a total of `factor` hashes for each server. Notice the for loop that appends the current value of `j` to the string `server[i]`, before hashing.

Combine this with Frank Pavageau's answer and you should soon understand what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for that link , it was useful ,  trying to implement based on that , but seems very confusing .

Answer (score 2):

I guess ketama hash is calculated using MD5. I found sample implementation [here](http://blog.chris.de/categories/10-Development)

```
public static Long md5HashingAlg(String key) {
  MessageDigest md5 = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException( "md5 algorythm found");            
        }
    }
    md5.reset();
    md5.update(key.getBytes());
    byte[] bKey = md5.digest();
    long res = ((long)(bKey[3]&0xFF) << 24) | ((long)(bKey[2]&0xFF) << 16) | ((long)(bKey[1]&0xFF) << 8) | (long)(bKey[0]&0xFF);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Duncan is right, just check the source to see how this particular implementation works.

However, conceptually, whatever the hashing algorithm used, if you need several hashes based on the same key, all you need to do is concatenate the key with several "constants", or at least known and repeatable values:

```
String key = "MyKey";
List<Integer> hashes = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : Arrays.asList("", "extra1", "extra2")) {
    hashes.add((key + s).hashCode());
}
```

And that's equivalent to distributing the hash around the integer "continuum", to reuse the article's terminology. So you can also do it that way, in the same way you can implement hashCode():

```
String key "MyKey";
List<Integer> hashes = new ArrayList<>();
int hash = key.hashCode();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    hashes.add(hash);
    hash = 31 * hash + 1234567;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frank Pavageau , but i guess this is not the same as that ketama hashing technique

Comment: It may not be the same implementation, but it's the same idea alright: generate a number of "hashes" spread across the possible int values.